# How to refer to an enum in the actual class rather than the base class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums, abstract-class

I am having trouble with this, as I have difficulty properly formulating it too. Making it harder to google it. I will try to explain as clearly as possible. I've simplified the code to make it clearer what my question is

I have an abstract class that has methods and properties that are used by all clases that have this as base class:

```
public abstract class TheBaseClass{

    //some properties here

    public enum MyEnum{} // this one every class has. It is pretty much empty here. Not sure if this is best practice.

    //some methods here
}
```

Then there are a number of classes based on this:

```
public SpecializedClass : TheBaseClass{

    //some more properties here

    public new enum MyEnum{} //every single class has a different enum

    //some more methods here
}
```

Now, somewhere else in the code, I have a method

```
public void MyMethod(TheBaseClass baseclassobject){

    //do stuff
    var usedforsomething = ((TheBaseClass.MyEnum)i).ToString() //i being an int. This is used to name something in a plot.
    //do more stuff
}
```

The reason for using TheBaseClass as a parameter for the method, is that before I had very long code that did what mymethod did for each class derived from TheBaseClass. It is not good to have duplicate code, so I made this method instead and wanted to call it with the parameter SpecializedClass (and many other classes like that also). The problem is that when calling TheBaseClass.MyEnum I naturally get the enum for the BaseClass, not the one from SpecializedClass. I have been experimenting with how to get the right enum in the method regardless of what baseclassobject I give it, but can't seem to find the solution.

**How can I get the enum of whatever class baseclassobject is?** I have tried some different things, but don't seem to work. **The problem I think is that the enum is not a property or method that I can call from the object, but rather need to call ClassName.MyEnum, which I don't have the className in the method.**

A solution could be to create a method for each class type, with that specific class type as parameter, but that seems like a lot of duplicate code.

For example if I have 50 different derived classes like SpecializedClass

Comment: But wouldn't `usedforsomething` work very differently if different enums where used. Would be interesting to see how you intend to use it.

Comment: I have corrected it a bit. In this specific context it is just used to extract what that enum in position i is called.

Comment: You should avoid shadowing (`new`) any elements in a class. It's a quick path to doom and destruction. Your design should 100% avoid it.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I just added it when doing this method. Normally I had no MyEnum in TheBaseClass, but a custom MyEnum in every specialized class. I can do this if it is better. But I still have my same issue

Comment: Could you use some sort of reflection to determine the specific type? And cast the baseCaseObject to that type dynamically?

Comment: @Marshall - Does `baseclassobject.GetType().GetNestedType("MyEnum").GetEnumValues()` get you closer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think reflection would be you only option here.

```
var usedforsomething = 
      baseclassobject
       .GetType()
       .GetNestedType(nameof(TheBaseClass.MyEnum))
       .GetEnumName(i);
```

But perhaps a better solution would be to add an abstract function `GetName` in your base class that your child classes must override.

```
public abstract class TheBaseClass
{

    public enum MyEnum {a,b }

    public abstract string GetName(int value);
}

public class SpecializedClass : TheBaseClass
{

    public new enum MyEnum {c,d }

    public override string GetName(int value)
    {
        return ((MyEnum)value).ToString();
    }
}
```

You could than do:

```
var usedforsomething = baseclassobject.GetName(i);
```

You can than avoid reflection and also the dependence on the child classes declaring the enum with the specific name `MyEnum`.

Answer (score -1):

May I understood you incorrectly, but did you try to do little reflection stuff in `MyMethod` to take necessary enum type:

```
public static void MyMethod(TheBaseClass baseclassobject)
{
    Type enumType = baseclassobject.GetType().GetNestedType("MyEnum");
    var usedforsomething = Enum.GetName(enumType, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(usedforsomething);
}
```

Comment: The OP's `MyMethod` shows that that wish to use a `int i` to index the `enum` value. You are ignoring that

Comment: I just wanted to provide working example. There is no `int i` declaration in original code.

Comment: The OP is fairly clear with it: `var usedforsomething = ((TheBaseClass.MyEnum)i).ToString() //i being an int. This is used to name something in a plot.`

Comment: Fair enough. Just clarify my reasons to avoid `int i`.